# Learning Event handling in Java

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, action, actionlistener

I am learning event handling using the Java Swing class.
I have trying different combinations based on a tutorial from the new Boston homepage. I hav made a class defining panels, JButtons, JTextfields, and Jlabels. I have made a class called "handler" which contains the ActionPerfomed-method, and I have connected two textfields (item1 and item2) to the addActionlistener method.
When I run my program I get the program to do what I want with the two textfields (this prompts a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog box to display the text I want.

The problem comes when I want the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog-window to display a certain text when I push one of the buttons:
-Instead of displaying the following text "You pushed button number 1!" as I hoped my code would do, instead there appears an empty JOptionPane.showMessageDialog-window.

I reccon that an experienced Java programmer would see whats wrong in my code hopefully easily.

Here is the part of the code that must be wrong:

```
private class thehandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String text ="";
        if(event.getSource() == item1)
            text = String.format("You wrote %s in field 1!", event.getActionCommand());
        else if (event.getSource() == item2)
            text = String.format("You wrote %s in field 2!", event.getActionCommand());
        else if (event.getSource() == button1)
            text = "You pushed button number 1!";
        else if (event.getSource() == button2)
            text = "You pushed button number 2!";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
```

Comment: The fact that the dialog pops up shows that the `ActionListener` is triggered. Since it is showing an empty string, the source of the event is most likely not what you are expecting.

Comment: Consider posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you sure item1, item2, button1 and button2 are properly initialized?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a `System.out.println()` before your JOptionPane call:

```
System.out.println("text=" + text);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
```

I bet you will find that `text` is an empty string.  Why?  Maybe your object references are null.

Another approach, which may solve your issue and doesn't rely on object references, is to use action commands:

```
button1.setActionCommand("doAction1");

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();

    if (actionCommand.equals("doAction1")) {
        // button 1 pressed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package EventHandling;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class EventHandling
{
     JLabel jlab;
    public EventHandling()
    {

        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Event Handling");
        jfrm.setSize(220,90);
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton alpha = new JButton("Alpha");
        JButton beta= new JButton("Beta");
        alpha.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                jlab.setText("Alpha was pressed.");
            }
        }
        );

        beta.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                jlab.setText("Beta was pressed.");
            }
        }
        );
        jfrm.add(alpha);
        jfrm.add(beta);
        jlab = new JLabel("Press a button");
        jfrm.add(jlab);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

        public static void main(String[]args)
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    new EventHandling();
                }
            }
            );
        }


}
```

This program will print in JLabel that which button you have pressed.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation of what you've done and why.